# Python, instance has no __call__ method

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

I am working with tkinter in python2.7. All I want to do is draw a canvas in one class, then class another class which will move a square around the canvas. But for some reason I get

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 495, in callit
    func(*args)
AttributeError: Animation instance has no __call__ method
```

From what I have seen, people get this error when they have over ridden a value, or a name shadows another. But I can't see what I might be over riding. Can anyone else see the problem?

**driver.py:**

```
from Tkinter import *
import animation
class Alien(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #Set up canvas
        self.root = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack()
        #Vars
        self.map = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        r = 50
        land = {}
        #Draw Init
        for i, row in enumerate(self.map):
            for j, cell in enumerate(row):
                color = "black" if cell else "green"
                land[(i, j)] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(r * i, r * j , r * (i + 1), r * (j + 1),
                                             outline=color, fill=color)
        self.creature = self.canvas.create_rectangle(r * self.x, r * self.y, r * (self.x + 1), r * (self.y + 1),
                                                     outline="red", fill="red")
        self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        #Action
        self.root.after(0, animation.Animation(self.root, self.canvas, self.creature))
        #Clost TK
        self.root.mainloop()
a = Alien()
```

**animation.py:**

```py
from random import randrange


    class Animation():
        def __init__(self, root, canvas, creature):
            self.x = self.y = 0
            i = randrange(1, 5)
            if i == 1:
                self.y = -1
            elif i == 2:
                self.y = 1
            elif i == 3:
                self.x = -1
            elif i == 4:
                self.x = 1
            self.canvas = canvas
            self.creature = creature
            for i in range(10):
                root.after(250, self.animate())

        def animate(self):
                #root.after(250, self.animate(canvas, creature))
                """Moves creature around canvas"""
                self.canvas.move(self.creature, self.x * 50, self.y * 50)
                #self.canvas.update() no longer needed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing in an Animation instance to after, which then tries to call it. I suspect you meant to create an instance and then pass in its animate method, right?

EDIT: So to elaborate a bit now that I'm back on the Internet; the problem is with this line:

```
self.root.after(0, animation.Animation(self.root, self.canvas, self.creature))
```

This creates an `Animation` instance and passes it to the `after` method, which then bombs out when it cannot figure out how to call it.  I'd do something like:

```
animator = animation.Animation(self.root, self.canvas, self.creature)
self.root.after(0, animator.animate) # get things going
```

Also, as pointed out elsewhere, the loop inside the Animation constructor is broken in at least two ways:

```
for i in range(10):
    root.after(250, self.animate())
```

sets up ten callbacks, all relative to the current time -- i.e. after a quarter of a second, you'll trigger ten callbacks at once.  And they will all fail, since you're calling the `animate` method and passing in its return value (which is `None`) to `after`, instead of passing in the method itself.  Or in other words,

```
after(ms, function())
```

is the same as

```
value = function()
after(ms, value)
```

which isn't really what you want.  One way to fix this is to add `self.root = root` to the constructor, and then do:

```
self.root.after(250, self.animate)
```

inside `animate` to trigger another call a quarter of a second later.

Alternatively, you can let Tkinter keep track of things for you; the `after` method lets you pass in an argument to the callback, and you can use that to pass in the `after` function itself (!) so the `animate` method doesn't have to look for it:

```
def animate(self, after):
    ... do animation ...
    after(250, self.animate, after)
```

and then set it off with a single call to root.after, passing in that method:

```
root.after(0, animator.animate, root.after)
```

Answer (score 2):

You give an `Animation` instance as callback to `self.root.after()`.  Callback objects are *called* after the given time.  *Calling* them means that their `__call__()` method gets called.  Your `Animation` class does not have such a method.  I propose to add one which then does whatever you want it to do.  For instance:

```
class Animation():
    #
    # ... your stuff from above ...
    #
    def __call__(self):
        self.animate()
```

Another option would be to give the to-be-called method to `after()` directly:

```
self.root.after(0, animation.Animation(self.root, self.canvas, self.creature).animate)
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides the already mentioned faults, you as well have

```
            for i in range(10):
                root.after(250, self.animate())
```

in your animation.py. Here applies the same: you want to give `root.after()` a callable, `self.animate`, instead of the result of calling this callable once (`self.animate()`).

The `()` do the call of the "thing" mentioned before. If you want to call it now, use `()`. If you don't (and you don't in this case), don't put `()` here.

Comment: And starting ten `after`s in a row at that spot probably isn't what the OP wants anyway.  It would lead to having ten animations after 250ms happening virtually at the same time (or very fast after each other).  He probably rather wants to have a linked `after` so that each animation leads to the next call of `after`.

Comment: well if we are on the topic of the after is there a better way of constantly calling it with out having a recursion overflow?

Comment: @EasilyBaffled Put `root.after(250, self.animate())` outside of the for loop, and additionally into the `animate` method.

Comment: `after` does not add recursion.  It just places a "reminder" in a list of what-to-do later and returns immediately.  A scheduler later will consider the "reminder" and execute the callback.  So, calling `after` in that animation method will not lead to unanchored recursions.

Comment: @Alfe You are right. If, however, the `after()` method would add itself 10 times to the list on every call, things would quickly become quirky, as we had exponential behaviour. And having 10000 calls after a second and 100000000 (if I'm not wrong) after another second wouldn't sound funny. If `after` adds itself exactly once on every call, everything will be fine.

Comment: Yeah, sure.  Don't make an avalanche.  Make a chain.